# dont cancle interstitial AD with backbutton

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

is it possible to make a interstitial (ad from admob) not Cancelable with the back button?
I only want that the user can cancle the ad just with the cross.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the interstitial is shown it is out of your hands. The Activity that shows the interstitial controls whether the back button event will be consumed or not.